# Extract numbers, letters, or punctuation from left side of string column in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

Say I have the following data frame which comes from `OCR` has `company_info` column contains numbers, letters, or punctuation and Chinese characters:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
id,company_info
1, 05B01北京企商联登记注册代理事务所(通合伙)
2, Unit-D 608华夏启商(北京企业管理有限公司)
3, 1004-1005北京中睿智诚商业管理有限公司
4, 17/F(1706)北京美泰德商务咨询有限公司
5, A2006~A2007北京新曙光会计服务有限公司
6, 2906-10中国建筑与室内设计师网'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), sep=',')
```

I want to extract numbers, letters, or punctuation from the left side of strings as columns of `office_name`, and the rest as a column of `company_info`. How can I do that in Python? Thanks.

The expected output is like this:

```
   id   office_name          company_info
0   1         05B01   北京企商联登记注册代理事务所(通合伙)
1   2    Unit-D 608      华夏启商(北京企业管理有限公司)
2   3     1004-1005        北京中睿智诚商业管理有限公司
3   4    17/F(1706)         北京美泰德商务咨询有限公司
4   5   A2006~A2007         北京新曙光会计服务有限公司
5   6       2906-10           中国建筑与室内设计师网
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column:

```
pat = r'([\x00-\x7F]+)([\u4e00-\u9fff]+.*$)'
df[['office_name','company_info']] = df.pop('company_info').str.extract(pat)
print (df)
   id   office_name         company_info
0   1         05B01  北京企商联登记注册代理事务所(通合伙)
1   2    Unit-D 608     华夏启商(北京企业管理有限公司)
2   3     1004-1005       北京中睿智诚商业管理有限公司
3   4    17/F(1706)        北京美泰德商务咨询有限公司
4   5   A2006~A2007        北京新曙光会计服务有限公司
5   6       2906-10          中国建筑与室内设计师网
```

Comment: I tried this one, but it gives me error `KeyError: 'company_info'`

Comment: @Yusufsn Exatly, same prob with me

Comment: @Yusufsn - there is space before `company_info`

Comment: @Yusufsn - changed in question

Comment: Thanks. Just one problem from your code, the company info in parentheses are missing for companies 1 and 2.

Comment: @ahbon - edited answer, inspiration from another one

Comment: Hello jezrael, I find one problem while using your method to my real data, when `company_info` before split and extract has no numbers, letters, or punctuation, after split and extract, those rows of `company_info` will be missing. Do you know how to deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: @ahbon - Is possible create new question? With these changed data?

Comment: Sure. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56106753/string-lines-get-missed-after-split-and-extract-in-python.

Comment: @jezrael May I ask, do you find where the problem come from?

Comment: @ahbon - Sorry, I was offline and then no time, so answering few minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
^(\d+),\s+([^\u4e00-\u9fff]+).*$
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `(\d+)` - Matches one or more digits
- `,\s+` - Matches `,` followed by one or more space character
- `([^\u4e00-\u9fff]+)` - Match anything except chinese character
- `.+` - Match anything except new line one or more time
- `$` - End of string

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zR1KAv/4/)