# Extract numbers and anything else into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of land plot area. The area column is messy. It starts with digits, then units come in different languages (or just no units at all).

**Raw Data** (EDITED)

```
city     year      area
A        2013      33107平方米
B        2013      3328
C        2013      34158.15平方米 
D        2013      11636.76 （合17.4551亩）
E        2014      13 m2
F        2013      24610平方米
H        2014      16243㎡/24.36亩
I        2014      235 45亩
```

I want to extract the numbers into a column, then whatever after the numbers into a separate column:

**Ideal Output**

```
city     year      area                      number             unit
A        2013      33107平方米                33107              平方米
B        2013      3328                      3328
C        2013      34158.15平方米             34158.15           平方米
D        2013      11636.76 （合17.4551亩）   11636.76           （合17.4551亩）
E        2014      13 m2                     13                 m2
F        2013      24610平方米                24610              平方米   
H        2014      16243㎡/24.36亩            16243              ㎡/24.36亩
I        2014      235 45亩                   235                45亩
```

Since most units are in Chinese, I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55703335/extract-numbers-letters-or-punctuation-from-left-side-of-string-column-in-pyth) and coded:

```
pat = r'([\x00-\x7F]+)([\u4e00-\u9fff]+.*$)'
df[['number','unit']] = df['area'].str.extract(pat)
```

and got

**Current Output**

```
city     year      area                      number             unit
A        2013      33107平方米                33107              平方米
B        2013      3328                      nan                nan
C        2013      34158.15平方米             34158.15           平方米
D        2013      11636.76 （合17.4551亩）   nan                nan
E        2014      13 m2                     nan                nan
F        2013      24610平方米                24610              平方米
H        2014      16243㎡/24.36亩           /24.36              亩
I        2014      235 45亩                  45                  亩
```

There are several issues:

1. City `B`: `area` has only numbers, results columns are all `nan`.
2. Cities `D` and `E`: numbers are followed by non-Chinese texts, results columns are all `nan`.
3. Similarly for cities `H` and `I`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df.join(df.area.str.extract('(?P<Number>[\d\.]+)\s*(?P<unit>.*)'))
```

Output:

```
  city  year                  area    Number         unit
0    A  2013              33107平方米     33107          平方米
1    B  2013                  3328      3328             
2    C  2013           34158.15平方米  34158.15          平方米
3    D  2013  11636.76 （合17.4551亩）  11636.76  （合17.4551亩）
4    E  2014                 13 m2        13           m2
5    F  2013              24610平方米     24610          平方米
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! However, I run into a problem - the code creates 3 extra rows for each row of data. Also, it splits the row into columns with weird information. For example, it extract `30122.94` into `895060` and `平方米`. Both the numbers and text are run... Do you know how to fix this?